# AR.js Object gets unvisible after setting attributes

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

i started to learn new skills on AR. And created an AR app on 8thwall.
In the begginning the project was about only place one object and drag it, scale it.
I added few more things like buttons to add environment multiple objects.

But there is one thing happens i couldnt figure it out.

When i place objects i can drag them and place where i want but when i try to scale it all objects disappearing.

The problem is i thing setting attributes to **<a-entity** , i am missing something or i dont know the rules.

```
const tapPlaceCursorComponent = {
  init() {
    this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster()
    this.camera = document.getElementById('camera')
    this.threeCamera = this.camera.getObject3D('camera')
    this.ground = document.getElementById('ground')

    this.rayOrigin = new THREE.Vector2(0, 0)
    this.cursorLocation = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)

    const button1 = document.getElementById('button1')
    const button2 = document.getElementById('button2')

    button1.onclick = () => {
      this.spawnModel('#treeModel')
    }

    button2.onclick = () => {
      this.spawnModel('#secondModel')
    }

    this.spawnModel = (model) => {
      const newElement = document.createElement('a-entity')
      newElement.setAttribute('position', this.el.object3D.position)
      newElement.setAttribute('visible', 'false')
      newElement.setAttribute('scale', '0.0001 0.0001 0.0001')

      newElement.setAttribute('gltf-model', model)

      newElement.setAttribute('shadow', {receive: false})
      newElement.setAttribute('xrextras-hold-drag', '')
      newElement.setAttribute('xrextras-two-finger-rotate', '')
      newElement.setAttribute('xrextras-pinch-scale', '')

      this.el.sceneEl.appendChild(newElement)

      newElement.addEventListener('model-loaded', () => {
        newElement.setAttribute('scale', '1 1 1')
        newElement.setAttribute('visible', 'true')
        newElement.setAttribute('animation', {
          property: 'scale',
          to: '50 50 50',
          easing: 'easeOutElastic',
          dur: 800,
        })

        newElement.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
          newElement.setAttribute('visible', 'true')
        })
      })
    }
  },
  tick() {
    this.raycaster.setFromCamera(this.rayOrigin, this.threeCamera)
    const intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObject(
      this.ground.object3D,
      true
    )

    if (intersects.length > 0) {
      const [intersect] = intersects
      this.cursorLocation = intersect.point
    }
    this.el.object3D.position.y = 0.1
    this.el.object3D.position.lerp(this.cursorLocation, 0.4)
    this.el.object3D.rotation.y = this.threeCamera.rotation.y
  },
}

    export {tapPlaceCursorComponent}
```

i think there is no need to share html file. I tried few things that doesnt work

- I set timeout after animation completed.
- Created a function called animation end and set object attribute to visible.
- Set default scale to my `model-loaded function`.
- add new camera to an entity `<a-entity camera="near: 0.1; far: 1000"></a-entity>`

Here is live version of my project.
https://nljcbmra-default-nextgen.dev.8thwall.app/cursorplace/

Comment: And also if someone wants to find title **'adding multiple objects to ar'** my thread may reference to others. Because there is no example project on whole web.

Comment: did you try re-creating this in vanilla aframe, without ar? Also, is it arjs or 8thwall?

Comment: thanks for commenting but i solved it my own and no i didnt tried to create with vanilla. I think 8thwall using preact. It is 8thwall project using aframe. @PiotrAdamMilewski

Comment: asked about 8thWall, because there's arjs in the topic and tags

Comment: @BatuhanCan I'm having this same issue that the entity disappears once the xrextras-pinch-scale is added, could you please add an answer with what you did?